# How can update jquery append keys, values data in laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel

Plz give me the best solution i have not concept and not finding the concept from last 2 days

i have a one form which including in create,edit file and in which some fields which appending with the help to jquery

appending successfully but are not update corrently when update or add multiple fields then again edit show only one input field

this is my code sample of update functionality
I want to update the jquery append value
**Controller**

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $request        = Request::query()->findOrFail($id);
        $params         = Param::where('request_id', $request->id)->get();        
        return view('admin.requests.edit', compact('request', 'params'));                    
    }
```

**edit.blade.php

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">                   
                        @include('admin.requests.partials._form', [
                            'url' => route('admin.request.update', $request),
                            'request' => $request,
                            'params' => $params,
                            'edit'    => true,
                        ])
                    </div> 
                  </div> 

@section('javascript')
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            var i = 0;

            $("#addParams").click(function(){          
                ++i;       
                $('#params').append('<div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"><div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"><div class="form-group"><input type="text" name="params['+i+'][key]" class="form-control" placeholder="Key"></div></div><div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"><div class="form-group"><input type="text" name="params['+i+'][value]" class="form-control" placeholder="Value"></div></div><a  id="remove" name="remove" class="action-icon  fa fa-minus-circle" style="margin-top: 10px;"></a></div></div>');                
            });         
        });        
    </script>
@stop
```

**form.blade.php**

```
<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="params" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="params-tab">
                    <div>
                        <a href="#addParams" id="addParams" name="add" class="action-icon  fa fa-plus-circle" aria-selected="false" style="margin-left: 16px;"></a>
                    </div>
                    @isset($edit)   
                            @foreach($params as $param)                         
                            <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="params['+i+'][key]" class="form-control" placeholder="Key" value="{{ $param->key }}">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="params['+i+'][value]" class="form-control" placeholder="Value" value="{{ $param->value }}">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            @endforeach
                    @endisset
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add all your response in content variable eg. 
content +="

+"response[i].name+"

";
than after loop you can do this

**$("ID_WHERE_RESULTS_SHOW").html(content);**

Comment: brother thanks for reply but i don't understanding that what you saying plz give me some example use my above code so that i will understand best